# How can i create ExternalDataUserAuth for Google integration

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials

I have created Named credentials with Identity type per User and OAuth 2.0 Protocol. Everything works fine if I go step by step in the Settings -> Authentication Settings for External Systems -> New, but I want all users to do it with Lightning Component through a click of a button.
With apex in the code below I try to list all of the users that are already in the ExternalDataUserAuth which works and I try to manually insert a new one and I get the following error:

> DML operation Insert not allowed on ExternalDataUserAuth.

What am I doing wrong and how can I insert a new ExternalDataUserAuth? Also if I can insert the new user through apex will the google authentication window popup so I can authenticate through it?

```
public void getExternal(){
List<ExternalDataUserAuth> existingAuths = [SELECT Id,AuthProviderId,ExternalDataSourceId,Password,Protocol,UserId,Username FROM ExternalDataUserAuth];
        for(ExternalDataUserAuth Auth : existingAuths){
            system.debug('AuthProviderId '+Auth.AuthProviderId);
            system.debug('ExternalDataSourceId '+Auth.ExternalDataSourceId);
            system.debug('Password '+Auth.Password);
            system.debug('Protocol '+Auth.Protocol);
            system.debug('UserId '+Auth.UserId);
            
            system.debug(ExternalDataUserAuth.getSObjectType().getDescribe());
        }
        ExternalDataUserAuth newAuthUser = new ExternalDataUserAuth();
        newAuthUser.AuthProviderId = '0SO5t0000008OIZGA2';
        newAuthUser.ExternalDataSourceId = '0XA5t000000GmkxGAC';
        newAuthUser.Protocol = 'Oauth';
        newAuthUser.UserId = '0052p0000098fK7AAI';
        insert newAuthUser;                    
    }
```